# What is the negation of the statement $S\cup T$ is a subring?

Tags: logic, ring-theory

I am trying to prove the statement $S\cup T$ is a subring implies $S\subseteq T$ or $T\subseteq S$. What is the contrapositive of this statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If $S\not\subseteq T$ and $T\not\subseteq S$, then $S\cup T$ is not a subring" is the contra positive. Remember, the negation of an or statement is an and statement of negations.